# Event Handling in Joomla Custom Component

Tags: event-handling, joomla3.3

I want to ask expert joomla devs out there, about event handling(dropdown values etc.) On how is it coded? In .NET(VB/C#) there is a custom event handler for every control in the User Interface during development (e.g button1_click). Any references?

Answer (score 0):

There are  aspects to this answer.

Firstly, I need to make sue that you are comparing .net web development with Joomla web development here. I would be surprised that every click on a .net control can be hooked into with a callback architecture, but then again I am not a .net developer.

Joomla has an event trigger system, which can be used in conjunction with Joomla plugins, see here: http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

On top of this, many more complex components define their own events, good examples are jEvents and jSeblod

Comment: thanks for the reference. However, I am only looking for simple event handling. I don't think I need plugins. Here is my example:
I have 2 dropdowns, the values of 2nd dropdown will depend on the value i will select in the 1st dropdown list.

Comment: There is nothing like this in Joomla

Answer (score 0):

This isn't built in the core of Joomla! and you would need to write some JavaScript/jQuery to handle this.

Alternatively, you could look at the likes of RS Forms which allows conditional displays for many field types.